# nginx - запросы от бота

Tags: nginx

В логе *error.log* nginx обнаружил записи:

> 2016/10/19 09:19:36 [error] 30110#0: *222886 open()
>   "/home/public/images/xxx.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory),
>   client: 123.123.123.123, server: site.ru, request: "GET
>   /images/xxx.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "site.ru", referrer:
>   "http://site.ru/"

Кто-то ботом запрашивал файл 40 раз в секунду в течение 12 минут.
Директории *images* не существует.
Файл xxx.jpg существует, но находится в директории *img*.
Наличие директории *img* для посетителя сайта очевидно, путь прописывается в адресной строке браузера при открытии картинок. То есть некорректную директорию *images* указывали боту намеренно.

В чем смысл запускать ботом такой запрос? То есть больше интересует, чего хотел получить бот?

Comment: есть разные варианты - от банально кто то хотел скачать картинки с сайта, но малость промазал в путях, ну с кем не бывает, до странных - например, это ошибка в конфигах nginx и в результате браузер перенаправляло сюда.

Я бы по айпи посмотре и понял -это целевая аудитория или нет. Если нет - можно просто забанить.